# Finding previously defined messages in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica by default defines a lot of useful messages for signaling common errors, like functions being called with the wrong number of arguments or files not being found. In general, I prefer to use existing, defined messages wherever possible, because it makes it easier for them to be handled via mechanisms like `Check`, `Quiet` and `On`/`Off`. However, all my attempts at finding what messages are currently defined have failed; obvious approaches like

```
DownValues[MessageName]
```

don't work at all.

Is there a trick I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a good question.  In principle, you can display any messages associated with a symbol by using `Messages[<symbol>]`.  However, according to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Messages.html?q=Messages&lang=en), the system messages are not loaded until the message is actually used.  But, `$MessageGroups` (new in 7) does provide a list of some of the messages available, but not nearly all.

**EDIT:** After some looking, I found the file `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Kernel/TextResources/English/Messages.m` that appears to contain all of the system wide messages.